# iOS - how to show tab controller on a new view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I like to know how to show tab controller on a new view.

I have 3 items on my tab controller: home, information, help

on home, there is a button that opens a new view, this new view called "beta" but does not show the tab controller, I am not sure how to show the tab controller, I dont want "beta" as tab item though..

any help will be greatly appreciated.

here is some code that i have used so far

```
//this is in appdelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{ 

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[InformViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InformViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[HelpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelpViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2, viewController3];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;



//this opens the new view called beta

@implementation HomeViewController

-(IBAction)Showbeta
{
    betaViewController *betaViewController = [[betaViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:betaViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];    
}

//this is in betaviewcontroller
@interface betaViewController ()

@end

@implementation betaViewController 

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        // self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController; --> this did not work
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I checked how its done in the appdelegate

Comment: but there it uses self.window.rootviewcontroller = self.tabbarcontroller;

Comment: I would recommend editing your question with the code you're using to attempt to instantiate the UITabBar controller. Also, are you using Storyboards, XIBs, etc?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/k1YUbExL

Comment: I am using XIB not storyboard. I have pasted snippets on above url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to make the view controller for that tab a navigation controller whose root is the home vc. Then when you want to show the beta view you just push it like any other navigation controller and it stays within the tab bar.

So you should adapt your code to something like this:

```
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[InformViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InformViewController" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController3 = [[HelpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelpViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1]

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
//self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2, viewController3];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navController, viewController2, viewController3];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the tabController instance in appDelegate class.
Now assign the your home view controller as the rootViewController.
On click of the button on home screen a new view appears which should have a tabViewController. So, you should now set the rootViewController as:
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController = tabViewController;

Comment: I am not sure what you are suggesting

Comment: are you using storyboards implementation?